# realloc in loop on win32

Tags: macos, winapi

simple code on C create 10 000 000 numeric in memory.
on Mac OS X work = 1 second
on Win32  Visual C++ 2008 work = 15 minutes

on Mac and Win32 2Gb memory

Q: Why?   realloc on Win32 work slowly when on Mac OS X?

```
// datrw.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
#include "stdafx.h" // add for MSVC  
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h> // // add for MSVC
#define POOL   9030000000
#define ARSIZE   10000000
//int main() // for Mac OS X compile as :  gcc datrw.c 
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) // add for MSVC
{
double *data,*temp;
//----------------------------------------create data
data=(double *)malloc(sizeof(double)); // add (double *) for MSVC
double c; // data for save
int i;    // cycle variable
for(i=0;i<ARSIZE;i++){
  c=POOL+i;
  data[i]=c;
  temp=(double *)realloc(data,(i+2)*sizeof(double)); // add (double *) for MSVC
  if ( temp != NULL ) {
    data=temp;
  } else {
    free(data);
    printf("Error allocating memory!\n");
    return 1;
  }
}
return 0;
}
```

if replace for :

```
for(i=0;i<ARSIZE;i++){
  c=POOL+i;
  //data[i]=c;
  temp=(double *)realloc(data,(i+2)*sizeof(double)); // (double *) MSVC
  if ( temp != NULL ) {
     data=temp;
     if ( temp == data ){ // add for optimize compilation
        data[i]=c;
     }
   } else {
     free(data);
       printf("Error allocating memory!\n");
      return 1;
  }
}
```

--
no result :-(

-- if delete realloc from FOR:

```
//----------------------------------------create data
data=(double *)malloc((ARSIZE+2)*sizeof(double)); // (double *) MSVC
double c; // data for save
int i;    // cycle variable
if ( data != NULL ) {
for(i=0;i<ARSIZE;i++){
  c=POOL+i;
  data[i]=c;
}
} else {
    free(data);
        printf("Error allocating memory!\n");
    return 1;
}
```

---

when is work !

BUT Why realloc in loop is BAD ??  for Win32 is BAD.  On Mac OS X - Ok

Comment: Try to compile with optimization (-O2 flag for gcc, and don't know what for  MSVC)

Comment: For your interest, test if `temp == data` in Mac case. In example as yours, maybe it is up to coder to optimize and reserve memory at once ;-) . `std::vector` anyone? It has better growing strategy (your code is cpp)

Comment: for(i=0;i<ARSIZE;i++){
  c=POOL+i;
  data[i]=c;
  temp=(double *)realloc(data,(i+2)*sizeof(double)); // add (double *) for MSVC
  if ( temp != NULL ) {
    data=temp;
  } else {
    free(data);
    printf("Error allocating memory!\n");
    return 1;
  }
}
-------------replace :
for(i=0;i<ARSIZE;i++){
  c=POOL+i;
  //data[i]=c;
  temp=(double *)realloc(data,(i+2)*sizeof(double)); // (double *) MSVC
  if ( temp != NULL ) {
        data=temp;
     if ( temp == data ){
    data[i]=c;  
     }
  } else {
   free(data);
         printf("Error allocating memory!\n");
   return 1;
  }
 }
---
no result

Comment: try compile gcc datrw.c -O2 on MinGW for win32 - result is bad too

Comment: The question is kind of pointless without you specifying precise environments. For all we know, you are linking to the debug runtime.

Comment: So you have discovered that the allocator used by your compiler under OSX runs faster than the allocator used by another compiler under Windows. Which only matters at all because you use a dumb reallocation strategy. Do not reallocate `size+2`, do reallocate `size*1.5` or `size*2`. Or, if you don't want to amortize allocatios, at least use something a little bit more sane like `size+500`. Allocating in increments of 2 is just insane. That's like complaining that exceptions are slow when you have 10 try/catch blocks in each function and throw 100,000 times per second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foremost, you're comparing performance of different C++ runtimes (libstd++ vs msvcrt), not performance of OSes.

There are a lot of different strategies of memory allocation. It's difficult to select an allocation strategy that will provide maximum utility, without excessively penalizing some behavior. For example, some strategies allows you to effectively allocate millions of small blocks, but they are not effective at (re)allocating huge memory blocks.

Generally, it's supposed that allocating small objects in not effective and developers try to reduce amounts of (re)allocations.

Another point is that MSVC does a few memory checks when a program is running in debug mode. It significantly slows the program down. Check you're running both versions in release mode.

Moving from theory to practice - always try to reduce amount of (re)allocations:

```
double *data = (double*) malloc( ARSIZE );

for( i = 0; i < ARSIZE; ++i ) {
   data[i] = POOL + i;
   ...
}
```

Comment: nothing. Build Release in VC++ - result bad too. malloc( ARSIZE ); - is good idea when we know ARSIZE. Program worked and dont corruped but very slowly on win32.

Comment: @user3016721, the idea is to not reallocate memory each time you have a new object. Allocate more memory than you need and realloc at the end. And in 99% of cases you know the size or can count it beforehand.

Comment: i dont undestand but compile in Release mode when not use realloc - result bad too
double *data = (double*) malloc( ARSIZE );

for( i = 0; i < ARSIZE; ++i ) {
   data[i] = POOL + i;
   ...
}

Comment: Thanks for all!  reallocate in loop is bad , but in example in Programming Books i look this code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::vector` like this

```
std::vector<double> data;
unsigned int reallocCount = 0;
for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < ARSIZE; ++i )
{
    double * p = i ? &data[0] : 0;
    data.push_back( POOL + i );
    if ( &data[0] != p )
        ++reallocCount;
}
data.push_back( 0 ); // what ever you wish to store +2 doubles for...
data.push_back( 0 );
```

It is quite evident that your Mac version reserves larger memory block than actually requested, and this is what vector does for you. Given C++ is your way to go. Reallocation `ARSIZE` times needs `ARSIZE` `malloc`s and `memcpy`s so cannot really run in less than 1 seconds.

You should test for `data == temp` as

```
for ( ;; )
    if ( temp == data )
    {
        printf( "Didn't actually reallocate, they are same" );
    }else if ( temp )
    {
        data = temp;
    }else
    {
        free( data );
        printf("Error");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT: making it even more funny, I added there `reallocCount`. On my machine, I get number of 41 as opposed to 10M !

Comment: real 1 second ! for check i write data : fwrite(data, sizeof (double), ARSIZE, iofile); and look on file 80 Mb for #define ARSIZE 10000000